# undefined reference with TH2

Tags: c++

I have defined a template function which is

```
template<typename T>
T*
addHistograms_temp(const std::string & newHistogramName,
              const std::vector<T *> & histogramsToAdd,
              int verbosity = 0);
```

And to call this function, i do

```
std::string histogramName_output;
std::vector<TH1*> histograms_1dinput;
std::vector<TH2 *> histograms_2dinput;
addHistograms_temp<TH1>(histogramName_output, histograms_1dinput);
addHistograms_temp<TH2>(histogramName_output, histograms_2dinput);
```

don't receive any error while calling with TH1 but when called with TH2 get following error

```
undefined reference to `TH2* addHistograms_temp<TH2>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::vector<TH2*, std::allocator<TH2*> > const&, int)'
```

I'll be highly obliged if some one can let me know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Where is `TH2` defined? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: TH2 and H1 both are defined in header file                                                                                                               #<include<TH2.h>, #include<TH1.h>

Comment: @Yunnosch, yeah got that and thanks for `[mre]` tip, it will be very handy :-)

Comment: Here is the full code                                                                                        https://github.com/HEP-KBFI/tth-htt/blob/saswati/src/histogramAuxFunctions.cc#L301                                                                        and header file is  here                                                                                                   https://github.com/HEP-KBFI/tth-htt/blob/saswati/interface/histogramAuxFunctions.h

Comment: It is difficult to post the smaller version as there is many dependency, it would be nice if someone could tell me from the code whether there is any mistake in defining the template function and the way it is called here https://github.com/HEP-KBFI/tth-htt/blob/saswati/bin/addBackgrounds2.cc#L187

Comment: As a rule you shouldn't need to specify the template type, the compiler should deduce it. What happens if you just write `addHistograms_temp(histogramName_output, histograms_2dinput);` ?

Comment: I checked that if I remove the implementation of template function to header file, there is no problem. Do I need to keep the definition and implementation of template function both in .h file?